# Reduce font in a LaTeX graph

Tags: fonts, pgfplots

May someone help me to reduce font to `\small` or `\scripsize` in may graph here by ?
How can I delete the `10^0` and replace it by `1`. It is a Log axisb ?
Thanks

[image]

My code is below. I have found a solution for the first part of my question by adding `font=\scriptsize`, but I don't know how to replace `10^0` by `1`.

```
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6]
\begin{axis}[font=\scriptsize,
legend entries={Tamisats,Volume},
legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)},
anchor=north west},
legend plot pos=right,
grid=major,
xmode=log,
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel near ticks,
axis y line*=left,
xlabel={Tamis $(\mu m)$},
ylabel={Tamisats $(\%)$}]
\addplot [mark=x,red,thick] table[x index=0,y index=1]{Classeur1.txt};
\end{axis}

%le second graph

\begin{axis}[font=\scriptsize,
legend entries={Volume},
legend style={at={(0.03,0.86)},
anchor=north west},
legend plot pos=right,
xmode=log,
ylabel near ticks,
axis y line*=right,
ylabel={\rotatebox{-180}{Volumes $(\%)$}}]
\addplot [blue!80!black,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.2] table[x index=0,y index=2]{Classeur1.txt};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please provide the code that produced the image so that we need not start from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you found answer for first part. But instead of passing `font=\scriptsize` to the options of `axis` do it for `tikzpicture`. Also instead of using `scale=1.6`, use `width=\linewidth` (or any width) in the options of `axis`.

Now to change the label for `1` you may define

```
xtick={1,10,100,1000},
xticklabels={,$10^1$,$10^2$,$10^3$},
```

so that the first entry `10^0` is not printed. Now print it using:

```
extra x ticks={1},
extra x tick labels={1},
```

Now you won't need `xtick`s for the second axis, hence use `xtick=\empty` there.

Also, to level the two y axes, you may use `ymin=-0.1`. With all these, the code will be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]%[scale=1.6]
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,
legend entries={Tamisats,Volume},
legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)},
anchor=north west},
legend plot pos=right,
grid=major,
xmode=log,
xtick={1,10,100,1000},
xticklabels={,$10^1$,$10^2$,$10^3$},
extra x ticks={1},
extra x tick labels={1},
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel near ticks,
axis y line*=left,
ymin=-0.1,
xlabel={Tamis $(\mu m)$},
ylabel={Tamisats $(\%)$}]
\addplot [mark=x,red,thick,domain=1:1000] {rnd};%table[x index=0,y index=1]{Classeur1.txt};
\end{axis}

%le second graph

\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,
legend entries={Volume},
legend style={at={(0.03,0.86)},
anchor=north west},
legend plot pos=right,
xmode=log,
xtick=\empty,
ymin=-0.1,
ylabel near ticks,
axis y line*=right,
ylabel={\rotatebox{-180}{Volumes $(\%)$}}]
\addplot [blue!80!black,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.2,domain=1:1000] {rnd}; % table[x index=0,y index=2]{Classeur1.txt};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Ignore the `domain=1:1000` , it is used only for demo as I didn't have your data file. Also, correct the `\addplot` line with `table` as I modified it for demo..

[image]

Comment: What the using of this command means  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

Comment: How can I reduce the distance between labels axis and axis please ?